# I want to select a product with attribute without stock

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm on prestashop 1.7.5.2 with PHP 7.0 and Apache.

I want to enable to select a product with an attribute without stock. Example :

Product 1 with 2 attributes.

Attribute 1 Stock = 1

Attribute 2 Stock = 0

When I select Attribute 2, the website doesn't select this attribute...

I want to select Attribute 2 and order it.

How Can I do this ? I don't want to disable the stock manager in Back-office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn this on from the Admin Panel in *Product Settings*:

[image: Product Settings]

[image: Product Settings 2]

Also make sure you set this up correctly at a product level:

[image: Product allow order out of stock]

This can be set when you edit a product, in the *Combinations* tab, at the bottom.